# How to create a countdown using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm having a really really difficult time creating a countdown clock using *moment.js* and this has been proven to be a pain.

So I have the **startTime** as `moment()`;
As for the end time (which is going to be where the countdown begins) I'm getting from a ion-range as String, so I'm using this:

```
const endTimeRaw = moment(
  this.formatedEndingHour.nativeElement.textContent,
  ['h:mm A']
).format('HH:mm');
```

that will give me a string '10:00AM' for example.

What I need to do is, in this case, 10AM - current time. I can't do it.

Can anybody help please. I've been doing this for over 6 hours and can't get it done.

Thanks

---

**ts**

```
async startTimer(startingTime?) {
    let startTime = new Date();
    const endTimeRaw = moment(this.formatedEndingHour.nativeElement.textContent, ['h:mm A']).format('HH:mm'); // This retuns 18:00

    return this.timeRef = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter = moment.duration(endTimeRaw, 'hours').subtract(moment().hours());
        console.log(this.counter);
        this.hours = this.counter._data.hours;
        this.minutes = this.counter._data.minutes;
        this.seconds = this.counter._data.seconds;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [`diff` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

```
const msLeft = startTime.diff(endTime)
```

Now you can create [a duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) to [humanize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) or [get that duration as a unit of time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/)

```
const duration = moment.duration(msLeft)
console.log(duration.humanize()) // "a minute", or "2 minutes" or "a day"
console.log(duration.asHours()) // 13 (or how many hours there are left
```

Comment: Hey @Alex Wayne thank you but It's still not working. I've updated the question and I added the method I'm using. Thanks bud